# What is the difference between mapping a drive and simply accessing it?

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares, shared-folders, cifs

What is the difference between mapping a drive using net use. 
*eg: net use x: \server\folder*

and simply going to start -> run
*type \server\folder *there and access it??

I use Windows 7.

I see that with the first method, only some of the files in that folder are displayed. I need to press F5 before i can see all the files.
However, no such thing happens with the second method.

Comment: When you say you have to press F5 to view all files after using the `net use` command, where are you attempting to view the directory list? I can't seem to duplicate what you are saying in the last paragraph of your post.

Comment: I am viewing the files in Windows explorer. My CIFS machine is configured as a standalone server and am using windows 7 as the client. So first I map the share using net use, then try to access a folder in it. Suppose it has 200 files. Only 184 are visible. When I hit refresh or go back and reenter the folder, all 200 files are there.

Comment: You should edit your question to explain better. As it is, it doesn't read the way you explained it in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You will have x: for future use. In case you access a server frequently, mapping will be convenient.

Comment: I meant in terms of how it access the share, is there a difference? Coz I see difference in directory enumeration with the two methods.

Comment: @xerocool Why not add the differences you see to the question so they can be answered as to how they arise.

Comment: have edited the question. Hope its more clear now.